# In iOS, can I jump to another app and make it auto login with account and password ?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two separate apps and I want to add a button in the first app and when the button is clicked it would jump to the second app.

The two products used the same server to login.

Can I pass the account and password to the second app to make it login ? And more, I want the second app to show the view I wanted which means I need the second app to init a specific UIViewController and make it visible.

Personally, I think passing NSStrings directly is not secure. I haven't seen such kind of jump between any products from the same company except those like Facebook and twitter, because their accounts are supported by apple and we can create an account in Settings.

Comment: Facebook actually does use URL schemes to login with apps, but it's passing apps authorization tokens, not login credentials.  If you're going to try to pass user names and passwords between your apps (which is kind of a clunky design), you should make sure that they are encrypted while being sent, and if they are stored on the disk.

Comment: I don't know a lot about authorization tokens. Can you give some examples ?

Comment: You can read more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), but they're not really relevant to what you're doing. The username/password transmission problem you're interested in is about encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use URL schemes to launch the apps from each other, and use the keychain to share sensitive data.  There are lots of blog posts about this, and [here is just one example](http://blog.speedwell.com.au/the-basics-of-a-shared-keychain/).

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own URL Scheme and use that to link to the other app - http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: I know how to link to another app. Can you give more advice on passing data between apps securely?

Comment: You could use a library like this https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor to encrypt/decrypt the data that you pass in the scheme

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
//UIApplicationDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    //do something here.
[self parseURL:url application:application];
return YES;
}
```